# With Grails, how do I retain information between different requests/controller actions

Tags: http, data-binding, grails, controllers

I have a controller like this:

```
def save = {
        def conferenceUser = new ConferenceUser()

        def conf_1 = Conference.get(params.conference.id)
        def role_1 = Role.get(params.role.id)
        def status_1 = Status.get(params.status.id)
        def user_1 = User.get(params.user.id)

        conferenceUser.conference = conf_1

        conferenceUser.dateParticipated = params.dateParticipated
        conferenceUser.accepted = params.accepted

        conferenceUser.status = status_1
        conferenceUser.role = role_1
        conferenceUser.user = user_1


          if (!conferenceUser.save(failOnError: true)) {
        render (view: 'participatedAdd', model : [conferenceUser: conferenceUser])
        return

       render(view: 'participatedAdd2', model: [conferenceUser: conferenceUser])

  }
}
```

Basically, this is the save controller of my 2-step registration phase. I want to be able to, after saving the first part, load the second view (participatedAdd2), but I need to keep the `conferenceUser.conference` value for the next controller action. How can I access this value in my second `save2` controller action?

Comment: in case this isnt possible, i want to fill this select box with that conferenceId information: <g:select name="conference.id" from="${conferenceUser}" optionKey="id" value="${conferenceUser.conference}"  />. How can i do so?

Comment: have you considered using web flow? (http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.5%20Web%20Flow) - you can easily store partial data between flow actions and save final object in the end ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `participatedAdd2` view, put a

```
<input type="hidden" name="conferenceUserId" value="${conferenceUser.id}"/>
```

in the form that gets submitted to the `save2` action. You can then look up the `ConferenceUser` in your `save2` action with:

```
def conferenceUser = ConferenceUser.get(params.conferenceUserId)
```